# Ko_selectize array object binding Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js, selectize.js

I have bind Ko_selectize  passing with array object

```
<select id="dg" data-bind="ko_selectize: { selectedValue:'id',selectedText:'text', data:'arrayobj', labelField:'text', valueField:'id', searchField:['text'], placeholder: 'Select' }"></select>
```

and my object binding code here

```
self.objarray =[];
     self.group.subscribe(function (value) {
        var av= '317';
        var a= value;
        var request = dataService.get('' false);
        request.done(function (data) { 
            self.objarray.push(data);

        });
    });
```

data received on json form
but dropdown bind with undefined

Comment: ko_selectize looks to be a third-party binding handler. Can you point us to the source code for it? Also, it looks like your "data" value in the binding is set to 'arrayobj', while the property is named "objarray". Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that custom binding expects to receive but this might be the culprit.

```
...selectedText:'text', data:'arrayobj', labelField:'text'...
```

"data" receives string here and not the object, you should remove those single quotes. And also as Travis pointed out, you passed 'arrayobj' but your observable array name is objarray.